# rtmedia uploading large image file fails

Tags: php, wordpress, cordova

I am uploading Image using rtMedia buddypress json API, every thing is working fine for small images but when it is larger around 4 mb is not uploading.

`I am getting 413 Request Entity Too Large.`

Changed the php.ini all the variables which is used for size to around 50MB but still no luck

The thing is if i use wordpress site which use same rtmedia it is uploading perfectly fine but when using mobile device which is developed in cordova the error i am getting

Searched lot's but couldn't got any perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by myself.

Actually rtmedia the image is converting to base64 string which became too large than the actual image. and that is the reason I was getting entity too large.

I have used file transfer plugin to transfer the file

and created my own function on the server using rtmedia class and is working fine now.